# Remove margin between the menu and the top and the sides of page

Tags: css, menu, margin

I need some help removing the margin that is between the top/sides and the menu.

I've tried for a while but nothing I do works. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/knickemackan/9qmm6yrt/ that I've prepared for you.

Thank you so much for helping me. Marcus N

```
 <div id="navigationwrapper">
    <ul><li>Home</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>
       Gallery
       <ul>
         <li>Music</li>
         <li>Videos</li>
         <li>Pictures</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>News</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: It's the `<body>`'s margin. Add `body { margin: 0; }` to your css and it'll work.

Comment: thank you. much appriciented!

Comment: @user3845474 Most web developers use some CSS declarations called *CSS Reset* to override the browser's default stylesheet, as a start point. It's worth taking a look at The Legendary **[Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**.

Answer (score 2):

That margin is from the `<body>`, remove it with,

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

---

It is a good idea to always use some sort of CSS Reset when you are working on a site.

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in
>   things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings,
>   and so on. / [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the body's margin. Give it no margin like:

```
body{
margin:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/9qmm6yrt/1/)